# From EE GeoTiff to MS Word PNG/JPG?

Tags: openstreetmap, geotiff-tiff, mac, png

I would like to put some images from Earth Engine (EE) in my report. So far I screenshot it and paste PNG on MS Word.

I see EE can export images to Google Drive. But its geotiff, I can't just paste it on Word, even to see them is tricky.

Curious how you guys do it or what's the recommended way to go? And interested the most in a solution that works on macOS as well.

Perhaps you are doing the following:
[GeoTiff convert to PNG with transparency?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41569/geotiff-convert-to-png-with-transparency)

Comment: What is EE....? (Earth Engine?)

Comment: Yes, question edited to make it explicit.

Comment: QGIS will open that GeoTiff and you can automate that to .png  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48386167/how-save-a-sattelite-image-in-earth-engine which is a similar request.

Comment: Tell me how to install QGIS on macOS after you have Anaconda Python setup.. too difficult. And QGIS is too big. Though good to point that question, I've seen it before, interestingly it has no accepted answer.

Comment: MacOS QGIS dmg https://qgis.org/downloads/macOS/QGIS-macOS-3.6.2-1.dmg or create your own Virtual Machine on your mac and install it in the VM.

Comment: Its exacly that dmg I'm talking about, it asks for python.org, not anaconda. Sure, VM is one alternative I experimented.